# Determine bluetooth audio bitrate on m1 mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth, apple-silicon

In my old MacBook Pro (2017), I can open up Bluetooth Explorer from Xcode's additional tools download and change bitpool or view transmission data. However, this tool seems to be gone from the recent version of Xcode's additional tools, which is what I've been using for my m1 16-inch MacBook Pro. Opening the app copied from my old MacBook Pro using Rosetta 2 works, but the app seems to lose all of its functionality.

I felt like the bluetooth audio quality I'm getting from my new MacBook Pro is lower than that from the old one. How can I determine the bluetooth audio bitrate used? How can I change the audio bitpool and verify that the new value is being used? (On the new m1 MacBooks running Monterey)